# Can't see "Report Data Pane" when creating reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I cant see "Report Data Pane" when creating reports. I've already tried the shortcurt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and looked for Report Data in the "View" menu. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and I have my report open. All I see is data sets.

I already tried researching but all I see are all the same procedures.

Comment: did you open report project?

Comment: The shortcut is CTRL+**ALT**+D, at least in BIDS 2008. Apart from that your question doesn't contain enough info for us to be able to help you, we can unfortunately only *guess* at the answer. You should add more details on what you've tried, and what your setup currently looks like.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+D worked for me in VS2010/BIDS 2008. Thanks!

Comment: CTRL+ALT+D worked for me too in VS2012/SSDT  Thanks!

Comment: CTRL+ALT+D worked in VS2019/SSDT as well.

Answer (score 61):

For users facing the problem *now*, using ***Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)***, *Business Intelligence Development Studio* / *SQL Server Data Tools*, if you find ***Report Data*** pane *missing* or you close it accidentally,do the following:

1. Click the '*Design*' of the report or the '*Design*' *pane* of report
2. Now in the '*Menu bar*' on the top, click *View > 'Report Data'*

### Note

If you directly go to the '*Menu bar*' without clicking the *design view* of the report (let's say you click somewhere in the '*Solution Explorer*' pane), and then in the menu bar, you try to navigate to 
 *View* > ???? you won't see '*Report Data*' option available

**See the difference**

*Not Available*

[image]

---

***Available :***

[image]

Comment: Been using VS for years... never noticed the "dynamic" nature of the toolbar until now...

Comment: That is a ridiculous hidden menu.  I cannot even think why that might be necessary.  I found several examples that said it is under "View" or press [CTR} + [ALT] + D, but those didn't work.  Then I found your example where you need to click in the report itself.  Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

1) Turn on Caps Lock

2) CTRL + ALT + D

Has to be a capital D for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The Report Data pane exists only since SQL Server 2008.  When you have a report opened in BIDS, in 2005 you have three tabs instead of the two that you see in 2008.  In 2008 you see the Design and Preview tabs.  In 2005 the three tabs were Data, Layout and Preview.  The **Data** tab is the "Report Data Pane" that you're looking for.